# Return is not working

Tags: javascript

```js
function trycatch(myfunction, name) {
  return function() {
    try {
      myfunction.apply(this, arguments);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e + name);
    }
  }
};
var rambo = {
  create: function(i, j) {
    return i
  },
  ramv: function() {
    aler("")
  }
};
for (var key in rambo) {
  if (typeof rambo[key] === 'function') {
    rambo[key] = trycatch(rambo[key], key);
  }
}

console.log(rambo.create(1))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I am trying to apply try catch to all my functions , but it seems they are not returning the values , Am i missing something?

Comment: try returning the result of myfunction.apply

Comment: Return Isn't Broken

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to do, but note that `trycatch` returns a function, so in order to call the function inside `trycatch` you need to use `trycatch()()`.

Comment: `return` is missed inside `trycatch`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you return from `trycatch` has no `return` statement, so it will always return `undefined`.

You need to return the return value of your call to `apply`.

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot to add `return` in `myfunction.apply(this, arguments);`. Currently the `trycatch` returns the function but that function do not return anything so you also need to return the function value of `myfunction.apply(this, arguments);`

```js
function trycatch(myfunction,name) {
    return function() {
        try {
            return myfunction.apply(this, arguments);
        } catch(e) {
            console.log(e + name);
        }
    }
};
var rambo = { create: function(i,j) { debugger; return i},
ramv:function(){aler("")}
};
for (var key in rambo) {
 if( typeof rambo[key] === 'function' ) {
    rambo[key] = trycatch(rambo[key],key);
  }
}

console.log(rambo.create(1));
```